# how to ask maven war plugin to copy particular jar file into warfile/web-inf/lib

Tags: maven-2, war

I have a simple.jar file that stay in c:/JAR.
When i used maven war plugin to create a war file, it will copy all the dependencies into lib folder.

How can i ask maven to copy simple.jar into lib folder as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578503/is-there-any-way-to-tell-maven-war-plugin-to-use-folder-other-than-target-classes Duplicate question

Comment: Indeed, this is just a slight variation of the other question (with the same solution).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe this will work for you.  I'm not 100% sure the `C:\\JAR` is correct though. You might have to fiddle with this syntax.

```
<build> 
 <plugins> 
       <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>2.0.2</version> 
        <configuration> 
          <webResources> 
            <resource> 
              <directory>C:\\JAR</directory> 
              <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath> 
            </resource> 
          </webResources> 
        </configuration> 
      </plugin> 
 </plugins> 
</build>
```