# Can I split class files of same java package into jar file and classes folder on Tomcat?

Tags: java, class, tomcat, jar

Say I use Tomcat AP server and I have 10 class files in package 'foo'. Can I, say, zip 8 of them into a jar file, put this jar file into 'WEB-INF/lib' folder and then put 2 of them into 'WEB-INF/classes/foo' folder. Will Tomcat treat them as a single pacakge when running webapp?

Note: I have a practical reason to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Maven War plugin. It can be configured to place specific artifacts into different directories in your War-file.

See the solution to this at: [Stackoverflow HowTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578662/how-to-ask-maven-war-plugin-to-copy-particular-jar-file-into-warfile-web-inf-lib/)

Comment: Thanks for answering anyway.