# Copy Maven dependency to webapp directory

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-war-plugin

this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3578503/154477) but with a twist.

I have a jar in a remote maven repository. This jar is actually a applet that gets run in the web browser. So it needs to get copied into webapp/resources/ directory.

I'm trying to use the maven-war-plugin to copy it and I'm so close but I can't seem to get the syntax quite right since the jar is just in the local m2 directory and not really inside the build directory at all (although I believe it is in the resulting war.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency plugin can [copy artifacts by maven coordinate](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) from a repository (local or remote) to arbitrary directories. Just add an execution of it somewhere before your war is built to copy the jar to an appropriate place.

Comment: I was able to find this helpful page which gave specifics http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html

Answer (score 1):

Try the copy task of the [maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/). This will let you call out your jar just like you do a dependency, but it will copy it wherever you like so that it can be included in your war.